# How can I validate that the max field is greater than the min field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a few sets of min and max fields in a form, where the user can specify a range by filling in a min and a max. I'm using jQuery's Validate plugin for my form validation. I'd like to set up a validation rule that enforces that the max field is greater than the min. This would be invoked whenever the max *or* the min fields values are changed.

I know I can set up some sort of basic custom validation method like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("greaterThan",
    function(value, max, min){
        return parseInt(value) > parseInt($(min).val());
    }, "Max must be greater than min"
);
```

And then add a rule for the max element:

```
rules: {
    maxTruck: {greaterThan: '#minTruck'}
}
```

But it's a bit more complicated because this only applies when the max field is changed, not the min. Is there any simple way to do this without having to write a lessThan method and apply that to the min field?

And then another thing I'd like to tackle - is there any simple way that I can apply this generically instead of having to enumerate each max field and which min it maps to? So that I can just have a min and max class and call something like:

```
$(".max").rules('add', { greaterThan: ".min" });
```

And somehow set up the method to be able to figure out (maybe based on a shared attribute?) which min the max field is paired with?

**Update:**

The basic logic that I mentioned in this post can be seen in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tUPQc/). However, I have not really worked on this much - I am looking for the logic to basically link sets of min and max fields the way I described. And I don't know if this is the best way to do this - as I mentioned, I'd love to be able to do this generically so that I don't have to refer to the min and max fields by id.

Comment: I think a **fiddle** will be great thing to start if you can provide one?!

Comment: Please clarify this question greatly.  In the beginning you state, _"invoked whenever the max or the min fields values are changed"_.  But then later you state, _"only applies when the max field is changed"_.  Which is it?  Validation occurs on the `keyup` and `focusout` events, so there won't be any need to worry about "when it changes".

Comment: In addition to a jsFiddle, please post your HTML in the question as well.  You have more than enough reputation to already know this.  I want to help you but too many pieces are still missing.

Comment: @Sparky - I want the behavior that it will apply the validation logic whenever the min or max fields are changed, but the code I provided only applies when the max field is changed.

Comment: It probably just sounds more complex than it is... again, provide a concise example for us to work with.  If I answer this question, I have no problem constructing a jsFiddle demo to go with it.  The very least you can provide is the HTML for the form.

Comment: There's not much for me to put in a fiddle, I don't have much code yet, I'm just trying to hash out the logic

Comment: Perhaps this question is premature?  How can you already know what works and what doesn't if you haven't constructed a form and tested it?

Comment: @Sparky - I have tested the code I provided - it works for when you modify the max field. I want it to work when you modify the min field as well, plus I'd love to rewrite it in a generic way so that I don't have to specify which max matches which min

Comment: So then what's the big problem with showing **all** of the code as per what you just described and putting together a jsFiddle?

Comment: ok, what I have set up is basically something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tUPQc/ . But I am looking for the logic/pseudocode to be able to implement this the way I described

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, here's something that should work. The rule is based on the built in [`equalTo`](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L1150) method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", function (value, element, param) {
    var $min = $(param);

    if (this.settings.onfocusout) {
        $min.off(".validate-greaterThan").on("blur.validate-greaterThan", function () {
            $(element).valid();
        });
    }

    return parseInt(value) > parseInt($min.val());
}, "Max must be greater than min");
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/tUPQc/2/

---

To make the rule a bit more generic, you'll have to need to use `addClassRules`:

```
$.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", function (value, element, param) {
    var $element = $(element)
        , $min;

    if (typeof(param) === "string") {
        $min = $(param);
    } else {
        $min = $("#" + $element.data("min"));
    }

    if (this.settings.onfocusout) {
        $min.off(".validate-greaterThan").on("blur.validate-greaterThan", function () {
            $element.valid();
        });
    }
    return parseInt(value) > parseInt($min.val());
}, "Max must be greater than min");

$.validator.addClassRules({
    greaterThan: {
        greaterThan: true
    }
});
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<input id="maxTruck" name="maxTruck" type="text" class="number greaterThan" data-min="minTruck" />
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/tUPQc/3/

Comment: +1 - I would only tweak it a little to meet @froadie's requirements for using classRules instead. See http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/Bxxmj/2/. Requires a `data-linked` attribute in the input.

Comment: @mccannf: Thanks--I missed that bit in the question. Do you mind if I incorporate your fiddle into the answer?

Comment: Thanks this looks great! One question though - the max field validates on every change/keystroke, but the min only when you leave the field... any way to have the min behave the same way?

Comment: How can this be applied so that the field is not required?

Comment: In answer to my own question:
Change this line:
return parseInt(value) > parseInt($min.val());
To this:
return this.optional(element) || parseInt(value) > parseInt($min.val());

Hope it helps somebody

Answer (score 4):

Simple and good way to use addmethod

```
$.validator.addMethod("greaterThan",

function (value, element, param) {
  var $min = $(param);
  if (this.settings.onfocusout) {
    $min.off(".validate-greaterThan").on("blur.validate-greaterThan", function () {
      $(element).valid();
    });
  }
  return parseInt(value) > parseInt($min.val());
}, "Must be greater than to field 1");
```

validating code

```
filed2_name: {

            greaterThan: '#filed1_id'
        },
```

second  i prefer first

```
$.validator.addMethod('le', function(value, element, param) {
      return this.optional(element) || value <= $(param).val();
}, 'Invalid value');
$.validator.addMethod('ge', function(value, element, param) {
      return this.optional(element) || value >= $(param).val();
}, 'Invalid value');

$('form').validate({rules: {
            fieldName1: {le: '#fieldID2'},
            fieldName2: {ge: '#fieldID1'},
             ...
      },
      messages: {
            fieldName1: {le: 'Must be less than or equal to field 2'},
            fieldName2: {ge: 'Must be greater than or equal to field 1'},
            ...
      }
});
```

Comment: If you're breaking your head why is not working be sure you compare int and not html value which is string. $.validator.addMethod('greaterThanOrEqual', function(value, element, param) {
      return this.optional(element) || parseInt(value) >= parseInt($(param).val());
}, 'Invalid range');