# ASP.NET Core 2 - Default number input validation is overriding my custom client validation

Tags: c#, jquery, validation, asp.net-core

I have two inputs that I need to validate against each other. They are a minimum and maximum. Here is the part of my view defining them.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="MinTubes" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="MinTubes" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="MinTubes" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="MaxTubes" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="MaxTubes" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="MaxTubes" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

And here are the properties that they are mapped to:

```cs
[Display(Name = "Min Tubes")]
[MinToValidation("MaxTubes")]
public int MinTubes { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Max Tubes")]
[MaxToValidation("MinTubes")]
public int MaxTubes { get; set; }
```

This results in `<input type='number'>` elements with labels and validation messages.

I have created two custom validation attributes to work with them. I'll only post the `MaxToValidationAttribute` class, as the other one is functionally identical.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CCM_Util.CustomAttributes
{
    public class MaxToValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
    {

        public MaxToValidationAttribute(string min)
            : base("{0} must be greater than or equal to {1}")
        {
            Min = min;
        }

        public string Min { get; set; }

        public string FormatErrorMessage(string name, string minName)
        {
            return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name, minName);
        }

        protected override ValidationResult
            IsValid(object firstValue, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var firstComparable = firstValue as IComparable;
            var secondComparable = GetSecondComparable(validationContext);

            if (firstComparable != null && secondComparable != null)
            {
                if (firstComparable.CompareTo(secondComparable) < 0)
                {
                    object obj = validationContext.ObjectInstance;
                    var thing = obj.GetType().GetProperty(Min);
                    var displayName = (DisplayAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(thing, typeof(DisplayAttribute));

                    return new ValidationResult(
                        FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName, displayName.GetName()));
                }
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        protected IComparable GetSecondComparable(
            ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var propertyInfo = validationContext
                                  .ObjectType
                                  .GetProperty(Min);
            if (propertyInfo != null)
            {
                var secondValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(
                    validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                return secondValue as IComparable;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
        {
            context.Attributes.Add("data-val-min", Min);
            context.Attributes.Add("data-val-ismax", "true");
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in Default.js, I have the following function being run as part of my `document.ready` function.

```js
function minMaxValidate() {
    $("input[data-val-ismin='true']").each(function (i, ele) {
        $(ele).change(function () {
            var maxName = $(this).attr("data-val-max");
            var minName = $(this).attr("name");
            var minValue = parseFloat($(this).val());
            var max = $("input[data-val-ismax='true'][name='" + maxName + "']");
            var maxValue = max.val();
            if (maxValue == "") { return }
            maxValue = parseFloat(maxValue);
            var validationMessage = $("span[data-valmsg-for='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']");
            if (minValue > maxValue) {
                validationMessage.html(minName + " must not be greater than " + maxName);
                makeError(validationMessage);
            }
            else {
                validationMessage.html("");
                makeValid(validationMessage);
            }
        });
    });
    $("input[data-val-ismax='true']").each(function (i, ele) {
        $(ele).change(function () {
            var minName = $(this).attr("data-val-min");
            var maxName = $(this).attr("name");
            var maxValue = parseFloat($(this).val());
            var min = $("input[data-val-ismin='true'][name='" + minName + "']");
            var minValue = min.val();
            if (minValue == "") { return }
            minValue = parseFloat(minValue);
            var validationMessage = $("span[data-valmsg-for='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']");
            if (minValue > maxValue) {
                validationMessage.html(maxName + " must not be less than " + minName);
                makeError(validationMessage);
            }
            else {
                validationMessage.html("");
                makeValid(validationMessage);
            }

        });
    });
}
```

The `makeError` and `makeValid` functions essentially just change the class of `validationMessage` to `field-validation-error` and `field-validation-valid` respectively, and they manage the submit handler.

I know that this type of validation setup works, because I am using it elsewhere without trouble.

I have stepped through the change handlers and they are working just as they should. However, after the error message shows up and the code exits, it disappears again. My guess is that .NET's default number input validation is taking over, and since the inputs are both valid numbers, it removes the error message.

Is there any way to disable .NET's default validation on number type inputs so that I can handle it myself and not have external black box code messing with my stuff?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here are the view and Default.js files in their entirety, just in case.

```html
@model Coils.CoilParts.Distributor
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = ViewData["ProgramName"];
}


<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Distributor</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Material" class="control-label"></label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Material.Key, ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Materials"]))
                <span asp-validation-for="Material" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Type" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Type" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Type" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MinTubes" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MinTubes" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MinTubes" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MaxTubes" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MaxTubes" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MaxTubes" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="InletSize" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="InletSize" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="InletSize" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PartNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PartNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PartNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Weight" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Weight" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Weight" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    breadcrumbs();
    measurementsValidate();
    minMaxValidate();
});

var cgi_menus = {
    'act': "the Accounting Menu",
    'adm': "the Administation Menu",
    'car': "the Corrective Action Request Menu",
    'cprA': "the A+Pro Menu",
    'cprC': "the CoilPro Menu",
    'crm': "the Customer Relations Menu",
    'dms': "the Document Management Menu",
    'eng': "the Engineering Menu",
    'etb': "the Engineering Toolbox Menu",
    'ldc': "the Refrigeration Load Simulator Menu",
    'mgt': "the Management Menu",
    'prd': "the Production Menu",
    'pur': "the Purchasing Menu",
    'qcd': "the Quality Control Menu",
    'rpt': "the Report Menu",
    'sls': "the Sales Menu",
    'sup': "the Administrator's Menu",
    'usr': "the User Management Menu",
    'utl': "the Utility Menu",
};

function breadcrumbs() {
    var tab = {};
    localStorage[curURL] = curProgram;
    if (sessionStorage.tab) {
        tab = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.tab);
    }
    else {
        tab.cur_url = "";
        tab.prev_url = "";
        tab.history = [];
    }

    // handle coming from an existing Perl CGI menu
    if (!tab.prev_url && document.referrer) {
        var menu_info = document.referrer.match(/cgi-s[\\/](\w{3})[\\/]menu(\w?)\.cgi/);
        var referrer = new URL(document.referrer);
        if (menu_info && referrer.hostname === document.location.hostname) {
            tab.cur_url = document.referrer;
            var cgi_area = menu_info[1];
            if (cgi_area == "cpr") { cgi_area += menu_info[2]; }
            localStorage[tab.cur_url] = cgi_menus[cgi_area];
        }
    }

    tab.time = Date.now();
    tab.history.push(tab.prev_url);
    tab.prev_url = tab.cur_url;
    tab.cur_url = curURL;
    if (tab.prev_url == tab.cur_url) {
        tab.prev_url = tab.history.pop();
    }
    else if (tab.cur_url == tab.history[tab.history.length - 1]) {
        tab.history.pop();
        tab.prev_url = tab.history.pop();
    }

    if (tab.prev_url) {
        $("#breadcrumbs").css("display", "inline-block");
        $("#breadcrumbs").attr("href", tab.prev_url);
        $("#breadcrumbs").html("< Back to " + localStorage[tab.prev_url]);
    }

    sessionStorage.tab = JSON.stringify(tab);
}

function minMaxValidate() {
    $("input[data-val-ismin='true']").each(function (i, ele) {
        $(ele).change(function () {
            var maxName = $(this).attr("data-val-max");
            var minName = $(this).attr("name");
            var minValue = parseFloat($(this).val());
            var max = $("input[data-val-ismax='true'][name='" + maxName + "']");
            var maxValue = max.val();
            if (maxValue == "") { return }
            maxValue = parseFloat(maxValue);
            var validationMessage = $("span[data-valmsg-for='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']");
            if (minValue > maxValue) {
                validationMessage.html(minName + " must not be greater than " + maxName);
                makeError(validationMessage);
            }
            else {
                validationMessage.html("");
                makeValid(validationMessage);
            }
        });
    });
    $("input[data-val-ismax='true']").each(function (i, ele) {
        $(ele).change(function () {
            var minName = $(this).attr("data-val-min");
            var maxName = $(this).attr("name");
            var maxValue = parseFloat($(this).val());
            var min = $("input[data-val-ismin='true'][name='" + minName + "']");
            var minValue = min.val();
            if (minValue == "") { return }
            minValue = parseFloat(minValue);
            var validationMessage = $("span[data-valmsg-for='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']");
            if (minValue > maxValue) {
                validationMessage.html(maxName + " must not be less than " + minName);
                makeError(validationMessage);
            }
            else {
                validationMessage.html("");
                makeValid(validationMessage);
            }

        });
    });
}

function measurementsValidate() {
    $("input[data-val-measurement='true']").each(function (i, ele) {
        var enforceUnits = $(ele).attr("data-val-units");
        var units = "";
        var hasMax = $(ele).attr("data-val-max");
        var max = 0;
        var hasMin = $(ele).attr("data-val-min");
        var min = 0;
        var value = $(ele).val();
        var validationRegex = /[0-9/.]+ [a-z./\^0-9*()]+/i;
        var name = $("label[for='" + $(ele).attr("name") + "']").html();
        var validationMessage = $("span[data-valmsg-for='" + $(ele).attr("name") + "']");

        if (typeof (enforceUnits) !== undefined && typeof (enforceUnits) !== false) {
            enforceUnits = true;
            units = $(ele).attr("data-val-units");
            if (hasMax != null && hasMax != false) {
                hasMax = true;
                max = $(ele).attr("data-val-max");
            }
            if (hasMin != null && hasMin != false) {
                hasMin = true;
                min = $(ele).attr("data-val-min");
            }
            $(ele).change(function () {
                var value = $(this).val(); // don't know why this has to be re-evaluated, but it does

                if (!value.match(validationRegex)) {
                    validationMessage.html(name + " must be a valid Measurement. (example: 12 in)");
                    makeError(validationMessage);
                }
                else {
                    $.post("/Validations/Measurements", { EnforceUnits: enforceUnits, Units: units, HasMax: hasMax, Max: max, HasMin: hasMin, Min: min, Value: value })
                        .done(function (result) {
                            if (result == "true") {
                                validationMessage.html("");
                                makeValid(validationMessage);
                            }
                            else {
                                validationMessage.html(name + result);
                                makeError(validationMessage);
                            }
                        })
                        .fail(function () {
                            validationMessage.html("");
                            makeValid(validationMessage);
                        });
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $(ele).change(function () {
                if (!value.match(validationRegex)) {
                    validationMessage.html(name + " must be a valid Measurement. (example: 12 in)");
                    makeError(validationMessage);
                }
                else {
                    validationMessage.html("");
                    makeValid(validationMessage);
                }
            });
        }

    });
}

function makeError(ele) {
    $(ele).removeClass("field-validation-valid");
    $(ele).addClass("field-validation-error");
    $(ele).closest("form").unbind("submit");
    $(ele).closest("form").submit(function () { return false });
}

function makeValid(ele) {
    $(ele).removeClass("field-validation-error");
    $(ele).addClass("field-validation-valid");
    $(ele).closest("form").unbind("submit");
    $(ele).closest("form").submit(checkFormValidation);
}

function checkFormValidation() {
    if ($(this).find(".field-validation-error")[0]) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

EDIT 2:

Here's a GIF of what is happening: https://i.imgur.com/eAiqxQJ.mp4

Comment: What is the meaning of  "after the error message shows up and the code exits, it disappears again." I made a demo to test your code ,but it seems that there is no problem . Could you share more details of the jQuery file and view file that can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: @XueliChen When I step through the javascript, it shows the error message just fine, but then as soon as the change handler exits, the error message disappears again. When I inspect the element, the class has been reset to valid. My best guess is that the default number input validation is overriding my own code. I'll edit the question to include the entire view file and Default.js file, but I'm not sure what relevance they have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is so often the case, the solution is "If you can't beat them, join them".

Instead of disabling jQuery validation on the elements that I am custom handling, the solution is just to lean into the jQuery validation library and use it the proper way. Everything remains the same on the .NET side, but the `minMaxValidate()` function becomes this:

```js
function minMaxValidate() {
    $.validator.addMethod("maxTo", function (value, element, param) {
        var $element = $(element), $min;

        if (typeof (param) === "string") {
            $min = $(param);
        } else {
            $min = $("input[name='" + $element.attr("data-val-min") + "']");
        }

        if (this.settings.onfocusout) {
            $min.off(".validate-maxTo").on("blur.validate-maxTo", function () {
                $element.valid();
            });
        }
        return parseInt(value) >= parseInt($min.val());
    }, "Max must not be less than min");

    $("input[data-val-ismax]").each(function (i, ele) {
        $(ele).rules('add', { maxTo: true });
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("minTo", function (value, element, param) {
        var $element = $(element), $max;

        if (typeof (param) === "string") {
            $max = $(param);
        } else {
            $max = $("input[name='" + $element.attr("data-val-max") + "']");
        }

        if (this.settings.onfocusout) {
            $max.off(".validate-minTo").on("blur.validate-minTo", function () {
                $element.valid();
            });
        }
        return parseInt(value) <= parseInt($max.val());
    }, "Min must not be greater than max");

    $("input[data-val-ismin]").each(function (i, ele) {
        $(ele).rules('add', { minTo: true });
    });
}
```

This adds methods and rules for the normal jQuery validation to run itself.

It does exactly what I want. Thanks to [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347177/how-can-i-validate-that-the-max-field-is-greater-than-the-min-field) for help.